# 6in4 tunnel inside OpenVPN tunnel - is that possible?

Tags: networking, openvpn, ipv6

I have a ubuntu server with public IPv4 address, and a router behind ISP-level NAT.

So to get IPv6 for my local network, I set up a OpenVPN IP tunnel. IPv4 traffic inside the tunnel has no problem, and NAT has been set for OpenVPN subnet so OpenVPN client can reach IPv4 internet via tunnel without any problem.

Then I set up a DNAT rule, to forward 6to4 traffic to my VPN endpoint:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination         
 DNAT       ipv6 --  anywhere             anywhere             to:10.2.0.6
```

I'm using a router from MikroTik, and I followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Hurricane_Electric_Tunnel_Broker_Example_for_Home), except I have my VPN endpoint's IP in local-address of 6to4 tunnel.

When I try to ping tunnelbroker's endpoint IPv6 address, I got timeout. Then I try to ping my client's IPv6 address from my other sever, which has native IPv6, it gives me Address unreachable.

I don't know if this approach will work, or what should I do to make it work. If not, what are other possible solution?

Comment: You need to be careful about this type of thing with IPv6 because it does not have fragmentation like IPv4 does, so shrinking the MTU with tunnels in tunnels could cause other problems. IPv6 also has a minimum MTU of 1280. You certainly need to make sure that ICMPv6 is not filtered so that PMTUD can operate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright - for some reason that I don't understand, tunnel-in-tunnel approach does not work, but I get IPv6 working by another way.

First, instead of using IP tunnel, use a ethernet (tap) tunnel. Then, on the tunnel server running OpenVPN, establish tunnel to tunnelbroker, and require a /48 zone from them.

After that, pick any address in your /48 zone, route it through the link-local address of your ethernet tunnel endpoint (client). i.e:

```
ip -6 route add <your /64 zone>::/64 via fe80::...
```

Go back to client, route IPv6 traffic through the link-local address of tunnel server. This is what I do on my MikroTik:

```
/ipv6 route add dst-address=2000::/3 gateway=fe80::...4%ovpn-tunnel
```

Then, set up IPv6 address on your LAN bridge, using that /64 zone you just routed to your router:

```
/ipv6 address add address=<your /64 zone> interface=bridge advertise=yes
```

That's it.

Comment: For the record, that's how you're _supposed_ to do it. Tunnel-in-tunnel is just outright silly.